# How do I change the css so lowering one class does not lower the other?

Tags: css, padding, word-wrap

I have two css classes.  One is supposed to hold images of text on the left side of the page and the other is supposed to hold a form on the right side of the page.  For some reason, when I increase the padding to try to lower the text images on the left side of the page, the form on the right side also goes down.  How can I fix it so that I can adjust the padding on both the classes independantly.  Here is the css:

```
.header { background:url(images/slider_bgpng200.png) top repeat-x; padding:0; margin:0 auto; }
.header .headertop{width: 100%; background: #d3e5e8; height: 30px;}
.block_header {margin:0 auto; width:1200px; padding:0; border:none; }
.formbox{float: right;}
.logo { float:left; padding:0; margin:0; width:242px;}
.slider { background: transparent; margin:0 auto; padding:0; height:383px;}
.slider .gallery { margin:0 auto; width:980px; height:383px; padding:0;} 
.slider .textholder {padding-top: 100px;}
```

And here is how it appears in the html:

```
<div class="header">
   <div class="headertop"> 
       <div class="header_text"><a href="#">Email</a> | <a href="#">Client Login</a> </div>
   </div>
   <div class="block_header">
       <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" width="242" height="94" border="0" alt="logo" /></a>
       </div>
       <div class="slider">
          <div class="gallery">
             <div class="textholder"> <img src="images/textimg.png"></div>
             <div class="formbox">Form is here </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.  The website is up at avidest.com/schneer.

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: Relevant fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kRAaV/

Comment: What are you trying to lower? Please modify the fiddle with lowered block and post a link to this updated version please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a float:left to the textholder.

```
.slider .textholder {float:left;padding-top: 100px;}
```

I also recommend using a inspecting tool to see what is actually happening. In this case you would have noticed that the textholder is a block-element that uses the full width of the container.